# What do you call it when a song constantly adds prominent rests? (like the example given)

Tags: theory, rhythm, rests, syncopation

Check out the first 25 seconds of

(Romance in the Night Sky [Touhou]). As is immediately obvious, it keeps hitting you with rests in a weird rhythm that completely throws one off. If you listen to the whole song, it just keeps doing that during the chorus in a really interesting way. My question is: is there a name/precedent for this interesting way of hitting a song with rests? I'm not sure I'd call it syncopation....

Comment: If you're looking to describe why it sounds so weird, I think the rests are a red herring. It's the way it emphasizes random beats and doesn't provide any reference for the 4/4 time signature (which is what it adds up to, but you won't "feel" it if you're not counting). The rests are also distinctive, but they're incidental to the rhythmic quirks.

Comment: Am I the only person around to whom it doesn't sound weird at all and the rhythm feels totally regular? Unless you count getting out of breath, I have no trouble dancing to it (yes, I tried).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, no, there's no handy musical term for "characterized by lots of interruptions by short rests." You *could* use the word *staccato* for this example, but that won't always be true. *Staccato*, applied to individual notes, means that the note is played for a short duration and released, not held for its true value. You could also use the word in a more general way for a passage that is marked by staccato articulation and is generally choppy and interrupted. Incidentally, the rhythm *is* also syncopated, since many of these isolated, emphasized notes fall between the beats.

But as is so often the case, the best way to describe "a passage frequently interrupted by rests" is... with those words.